# How to make UIButton in switch case selected and unselected?

Tags: xcode, uibutton

Can anyone help with how to make a button unselected after I press another button.

I have 3 buttons and do not know how to make previous button look like unselected in switch case, after touch they change state to selected Yes and change their pics.

```
-(IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch(pressedButton.tag)
    {
    case 0:
          pressedButton.selected=YES;
          red = 255.0/255.255;
          green = 0.0/255.255;
          blue = 0.0/255;
    break;
    case 1:
          pressedButton.selected=YES;
          red = 0.0/255.255;
          green = 0.0/255.255;
          blue = 255.0/255;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before the switch:

```
for(UIView *v in sender.superview.subviews) {
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
           [v setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

assumption all buttons are next to each other :)
else you would need IBOutlets to the buttons

Comment: Thank you! I'm using IBOutlets and works almost perfectly. some times need to tap first button few times to change its state. (( other 2 buttons work without problems.